# Removing a tuple from a list when it fails to meet certain conditions

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples, and I want to remove a tuple if the the first element in the tuple does not have a number within it. Below is the code I currently have.

```
x = [('akj_vx', 1.2559392760527808, 1.0), ('39Sbw£', 1.5930205922, 2.0), ('bg1HEw*', 1.95830294, 1.0)]

for item in x:
  print("Time", item[1],": ID", item[0], "Exponent", item[2],)
  if re.search(r"\d", item[0]):
    print("Task", item[0] ,"Accepted \n")
  else:
    print("Task", item[0], "discarded \n")

print(x)
```

When I print my list (x), I want the output to be:

```
[('39Sbw£', 1.5930205922, 2.0), ('bg1HEw*', 1.95830294, 1.0)]
```

What can I add to my code to ensure this?

Comment: you could intialize a `ret=[]` before loop and do `ret.append(item)` if `search` is successful.

Comment: That would be overkill - se answers below

Comment: @CutePoison that's not overkill, it's just not very Pythonic. In fact, iteratively appending to an empty sequence is how beginners *should* learn before moving on to list comprehensions.

Comment: I do agree with that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to create a list satisfying the criterion instead of removing the unnecessary items:

```
x = [item for item in x if re.search(r"\d", item[0])]
```

Alternatively, you can use pure Python as well (without any module dependency):

```
x = [item for item in x if any(y.isdigit() for y in item[0])]
```

---

As requested in comments, you could also remove by index (not recommended):

```
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    if not any(y.isdigit() for y in item[0]):
        del x[i]
```

Comment: Is there a way of removing them via index? For instance, using x.remove()?

Comment: `remove` actually removes the first found element and not by index. There is no need to do by index but you could try using `del`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some list comprehension: `L=[item for item in x if re.search(r"\d", item[0])]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `re` module, you can use this:

```
x = [('akj_vx', 1.2559392760527808, 1.0), ('39Sbw£', 1.5930205922, 2.0), ('bg1HEw*', 1.95830294, 1.0)]

x = [i for i in x if any(ch in '0123456789' for ch in i[0])]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[('39Sbw£', 1.5930205922, 2.0), ('bg1HEw*', 1.95830294, 1.0)]
```

EDIT (or use `.isdigit()`):

```
x = [i for i in x if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in i[0])]
```

Comment: Why not use `ch.isdigit()`?